# Cournot oligopoly game with N firms

Tags: game-theory

This is the full question: **Find all pure strategy Nash equilibria of the Cournot oligopoly game with N firms facing linear demand** $P = a − Q$ **when the total cost for each firm is** $c_i(q_i) = q_i^2 $

My understanding is that:

$$\Pi_i =q_i(a − Q) - q_i^2$$

$$\max_{q_i} [qi(a − Q) - qi^2]$$

Therefore, the FOC is:

$$a-Q-2q_i=0$$

This  is the FOC  for each firm.

This is the part that I get stuck at. How do you add all the FOCs of N firms together? Thank you!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Your FOC is wrong! You did not have taken into account that Q is the joint production of all firms, and not a parameter, i.e., $Q=\sum_{i \in N}\,q_{i}$. Then you get  $q_{i}=(a-\sum_{j \in N\backslash\{i\}}\,q_{j})/4$ for all $i \in N$. Hence, solving the system of FOC, you will get a Nash equilibrium.